# Javascript: Calculate time difference between 2 days with conversion to UTC

Tags: javascript, date, utc

I have a start and end dates, I need to convert them to UTC and calculate how many days are in between (including).

So for example:

(01/08/15 10:00 GMT+3) - (04/08/15 10:00 GMT+3) will **return 4**

(01/08/15 00:00 GMT+3) - (04/08/15 10:00 GMT+3) will **return 5**

The following code works for those dates like the first case, but not for the second (where after the conversion there is an additional day):

```
var startDateInUTC = new Date(start.getUTCFullYear(), start.getUTCMonth(), start.getUTCDate(), start.getUTCHours(), start.getUTCMinutes(), start.getUTCSeconds());
var endDateInUTC = new Date(end.getUTCFullYear(), end.getUTCMonth(), end.getUTCDate(), end.getUTCHours(), end.getUTCMinutes(), end.getUTCSeconds());
var totalDays = Math.floor((endDateInUTC - startDateInUTC) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) + 1;
```

I tried changing the **Math.floor** to **Math.round** but that just adds me a day in some scenarios.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is not worthy of being an answer, but is using external libraries an option? [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) is a very robust library for everything time-related - in my experience, working with time objects manually is just a bottomless pit of edge-cases.

Comment: take a look at `moment.js`

Comment: Isn't (01/08/15 00:00 GMT+3) = (31/07/15 21:00 GMT)? So, the calculation returning 5 seems correct.

Comment: @Kerem, doesn't make a difference, both dates get calculated back to UTC. So difference is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function calculate(start, end)
{

var startDateInUTC = new Date(start.getUTCFullYear(), start.getUTCMonth(), start.getUTCDate(), start.getUTCHours(), start.getUTCMinutes(), start.getUTCSeconds());
var endDateInUTC = new Date(end.getUTCFullYear(), end.getUTCMonth(), end.getUTCDate(), end.getUTCHours(), end.getUTCMinutes(), end.getUTCSeconds());

return Math.floor(millisecondsToDays = (Date.parse(endDateInUTC) - Date.parse(startDateInUTC)) / 1000 / 3600 / 24);

}
console.log(calculate(new Date("2015/08/01 10:00:00"), new Date("2015/08/04 10:00:00")));
console.log(calculate(new Date("2015/08/01 00:00:00"), new Date("2015/08/04 10:00:00")));

//the answer in both cases will be 3
```

Use `Date.parse` here. It will convert the dates into `timeStamps`. you can subtract these and then calculate the amount back to days. Use `Math.floor` to round down, since `6.25` is 6 days and 6 hours.

`timeStamps` are the amount of milliseconds that have passed since `1970/01/01 00:00:00`. That date is always UTC. When you have two timestamps you can calculate the difference between them. `Date.parse()` returns the timestamp on a valid date. `new Date(timestamp)` will return the date based upon the timestamp.

To get date barriers you can do an extra calculation:

```
(start time + 24 * days + end time) / 24
```

Round this figure down and you get the day barriers.

Example:

```
21 + 24 * 3 + 7 = 100
103 / 24 = 4.1666666.....

Math.floor(4.166666) = 4;
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. I believe that doesn't solve this case.
The timezones is unaccounted for. So for GMT+3 `2015/08/01 01:00 - 2015/08/01 10:00` should actually return 2 days, while `2015/08/01 03:05 - 2015/08/01 10:00` still returns 1

Comment: the example you give in your comment matches 9 hours. That isn't a day, it's zero days and 9 hours. In UTC this will be the same, expect there will be a day barrier between them. Do you want to count the day barriers?

Comment: Yes I do, after conversion to UTC I want to count every day it hits. So if the start time is somewhere in Sunday, end time is somewhere in Monday, it would count as 2 days even though it might be less than 24 hours

Comment: Thanks I believe that solves it, but I ended up solving it in a different way, as I'll post in a second.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up gathering a pretty simple solution combining some bits of Mouser's answer (Thanks!)

```
function calcStreamDaysInUTC(start, end) {
    try {
        // Translate to UTC
        var startDateInUTC = new Date(start.getUTCFullYear(), start.getUTCMonth(), start.getUTCDate(), start.getUTCHours(), start.getUTCMinutes(), start.getUTCSeconds());
        var endDateInUTC = new Date(end.getUTCFullYear(), end.getUTCMonth(), end.getUTCDate(), end.getUTCHours(), end.getUTCMinutes(), end.getUTCSeconds());
        // Reset everything but the date
        startDateInUTC.setHours(0);
        startDateInUTC.setMinutes(0);
        startDateInUTC.setSeconds(0);
        endDateInUTC.setHours(0);
        endDateInUTC.setMinutes(0);
        endDateInUTC.setSeconds(0);

        var totalDays = (endDateInUTC - startDateInUTC) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) + 1;
        return totalDays;
    } catch (e) {
        return -1;
    }
}
```